# Remove hold from question

Tags: support

My [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56443/what-movie-contains-a-scene-of-jackie-chan-grabbing-the-pump-action-of-his-oppon) was put on hold as "off topic" with further note that "Identification questions must contain sufficient detail."

I have added as much detail as I remember, and have since received 1 upvote. Is it possible to have the hold removed?

Comment: It's already in the reopen queue... just requires 5 people total to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About an hour after you posted this, 2 users and a mod voted to reopen. It has been reopened at this point.